# ou:dn:= search work well in openldap but not work in AD

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have setup both AD and OpenLDAP server and I need to filter object in one specified OU.

I have to use the root node as base DN, so I try to use `ou:dn:=OuName` to filter object, it work well in openldap search can query out any object under specified OU, but in AD I can only get ou itself, but no children under it.

Is there any alternative to filter all object under one ou in AD? And why it is work in OpenLdap but not in AD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active Directory is not completely LDAP compliant. They kind of do their own thing. There are many oddities specific to AD. This is one of them. That filter just doesn't work the way it does in OpenLDAP.

In fact, AD doesn't allow you to do any partial matches on any attribute that contains a DN, so you can't even do something like `(distinguishedName=*,OU=Something,DC=example,DC=com)`

The only way to filter results to one OU in AD is by setting the base DN to that OU.